# frame not set on UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

[image: cell frame layout]

I have used tableview. On tableviewcell, I used uiview.

But I want to change the x position accroding to need.

I have used this code:-

```
if ([[[allDetailArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"sender_name"] isEqual: @"Admin"] ) {
        [cell.MnView setFrame:CGRectMake(37,8,275,76)];
}
else
{
        [cell.MnView setFrame:CGRectMake(5,8,275,76)];
}
```

When we run, it will perfect but when we scroll tableview for seeing the next rows the view position in not show perfectly.

Comment: add screenshots

Comment: please check my screen shot and help me..

Comment: Can you please add the screenshots after scrolling the table view so that I can see exactly what issue you are actually facing?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving hardcoded values of frames programmatically, you can take the `IBoutlet` of layout constrains of `MnView` in customCellView class and then adjust that constraints accordingly in your if-else code.

Comment: I have use outlet of UIVIew name as MnView. so please see my screenshot and provide any way to solve my problem.

Comment: You must used Autolayout in MnView in CustomCell. Create new outlet for constraints also and adjust this new outlet instead frame.

Comment: But i use Autoresizing in whole app, can you provide the code.